# Merge list together based on common values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list

```
a = [(1,2),(1,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,7)]
```

I want to merge the values in the lists in groups so I can get:

```
b = [(1,2,3),(4,5),(6,7,8)]
```

The order doesn't matter, but the group based on connectivity matters. Haven't been able to figure out a way to do it, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set intersection to test if there's any value in common between two sets, and you can use set union to merge the two sets:

```
b = []
for p in map(set, a):
    for i, s in enumerate(b):
        if s & p:
            b[i] |= p
            break
    else:
        b.append(p)
```

`b` becomes:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {8, 6, 7}]
```

You can then convert it to your desired list of sorted tuples if you want:

```
b = [tuple(sorted(s)) for s in b]
```

`b` becomes:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

some for loops will do the job:

```
a = [(1,2),(1,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,7)]

unions = [[i1,i2]  for i1,x in enumerate(a) for i2,y in enumerate(a) for z in x if z in y and i2!=i1]

for c in unions:
    if c[::-1] in unions: unions.remove(c[::-1])

b = [e for i,e in enumerate(a) if i not in [y for x in unions for y in x]]

for c in unions:b.append(tuple(set(a[c[0]]+a[c[1]])))

print sorted(b)
```